# Android APP for Real time Audio Classification based on "Transfer learning with YAMNet for environmental sound classification"

Tags: android, tensorflow, audio, transfer-learning, tflite

I have been following "Transfer learning with YAMNet for environmental sound classification". I am not very familiar with android studio and custom tflite models. Can anyone help me create Android App for Real time Classfication please?

I am confused as how to go further. I also tried using tflite model maker but was not able to download/install it.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can use codelabs steps to do it https://developers.google.com/codelabs/tflite-audio-classification-basic-android?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Flearn%2Fpathways%2Fget-started-audio-classification%23codelab-%2Fcodelabs%2Ftflite-audio-classification-basic-android#1
this helps to make an android application use latest version of android studio